# Exchanging in Jaipur

Tags: jaipur

One of the actions you can do on your turn in Jaipur is to trade cards from your hand with an equal amount of cards from the market. I wasn't sure how this worked mechanically as well as its interaction with the 7-card hand limit.

- I have 6 cards in hand
- I take two cards from the market, my hand is now 8
- I put two cards back into the market, my hand is 6 again

Is this a legal move, or at no point can my hand exceed 8? I would think inbetween an action resolving, you can have >7 cards in hand but the rules are ambiguous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a perfectly acceptable action to take.

[The rules](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/55f65034e4b0f8a9c68669fd/t/56171c19e4b03950d6c466a6/1444355097680/jaipur+rulebook.pdf) at the bottom of the "Take Cards" page explicitly state:

> Players may never have more than 7 cards in their hand **at the end of their turn.**

Nowhere in the rules does it disallow gaining more than 7 cards to your hand during an exchange.